# login into two websites with one database php

Tags: php, session, laravel

I have two websites in laravel (website1 and website2) on the same server and I 'm using one database.

Both have their login access. When I login into website1 and next login into website2, I lose access to website1.

I create just one database because i'm using same information on each websites like users, groups. Is it possible to login each website at the same time without losing their access?

Thanks

Comment: it might be due to messup your coding, ... million website can run in single database...

Answer (score 0):

Use the cookie as session driver and set different cookie prefixes for your laravel applications. Don't forget to clean your browsers cache and cookie.